# Товар по цене

Tags: sql

Помогите, пожалуйста. Как вывести товар с ценой больше 100,

Answer (score 1):

**Upd**

```
select 
    p.*
    from products p
    where
        p.id_product in
            (select distinct pr.id_product
            from prices pr
            where pr.price > 100
        )
        and p.id_product in
            (select distinct ms.id_product
            from magazine_sales ms
            join sale s on s.id_sale = ms.id_sale
            where year(s.date_sale) < 2012
        )
        and (select count(distinct s1.id_customer)
            from sale s1
            join magazine_sales ms1 on ms1.id_sale = s1.id_sale
            where ms1.id_product = p.id_product
        ) = 1
```

проверить негде, но должно работать.

Comment: подправил запос, исправил ошибку с count.